# Do properties instantiate when class is instantiated?

Tags: c#

I'm wondering if a properties get{} is created when it's container class is:

e.g.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyProperty1 { get { return new MyClass1("Whatever"); }
    public MyProperty2 { get { return new MyClass2("Whatever"); }
    public MyProperty3 { get { return new MyClass3("Whatever"); }
    // so on
}
```

So when i do:

```
var myClass = new MyClass();
```

Does this initialize all the properties (ie new MyClass1, new MyClass2, etc) or are they only created/initialized when I access them like this:

```
myClass.MyProperty1.SomeMethodInsideMyClass1();
```

In this example, lets say whatever method made this call, only needs MyClass1 methods, but not the rest, which is why I'd like to know if this will cause any unnecessary overhead.

Comment: A property/function/method on an object doesn't execute until you call it. What would make think it does?

Comment: I didn't give you the -1, but your question doesn't fit SO.  SO if for people that have a problem and they are looking for a solution. Your question falls in the category of a teaching aid before the problem. People come here because they have a problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Properties are actually methods behind the scene, so it does not make sense to ask if they get "instantiated": methods are never instantiated.

In your example, new instances of `ClassX` are created only when the property's getter method is accessed. In other words, if some user needs only `MyProperty1`, him instantiating the `MyClass` object would *not* instantiated anything else.

The timing on instantiation depends entirely on your implementation of the class. In your example, you create a new instance in the getter. However, this is not the only way to go: one could conceivably pre-instantiate the properties into private fields, and then return the fields, like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly MyClass1 prop1 = new MyClass1("Whatever");
    private readonly MyClass2 prop2 = new MyClass2("Whatever");
    private readonly MyClass3 prop3 = new MyClass3("Whatever");
    public MyProperty1 { get { return prop1; }
    public MyProperty2 { get { return prop2; }
    public MyProperty3 { get { return prop3; }
    // so on
}
```

This implementation is different - it instantiates upfront all the values for the fields *baking* the properties. However, this behavior of the class is independent of its properties.